# Android Custom Scrollbar and fastScrollEnabled

Tags: android, xml, scrollbar, xml-drawable, custom-scrolling

I just want a custom scrollbar in my Listview with fastScrollEnabled but this doesn´t work!
With fastScroll enabled, the custom scrollbar is not visible when scrolling normal and when scrolling fast, it's the default scrollbar. 
Without fastScrollEnabled is does work like it should be.

---

res\values\Styles.xlm:

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:scrollbarThumbVertical">@drawable/scrollbar</item>
    <item name="android:fastScrollThumbDrawable">@drawable/scrollbar</item>
    <item name="android:fastScrollTrackDrawable">@drawable/scrollbar</item>
</style>
...
```

res\drawable\scrollbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<gradient
    android:angle="45"
    android:endColor="#CC3401"
    android:centerColor="#CC5c33"
    android:startColor="#CC3401" />

<corners android:radius="8dp" />
<size android:width="4dp"/>
<padding
    android:left="0.5dp"
    android:right="0.5dp" />
</shape>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <application
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

My Listview:

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff000020"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true">
</ListView>
```

Can anyone please tell me what´s wrong here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

**UPDATE**

The short answer is: "thumb" and "track"are different things, do not put same style. When you area using "fastScrollbarEnabled", the "track" needs to have height and width.

---

*old answer below*

Apparently you need specify the "thumb" height when with the "fastScrollEnabled" enabled. You are putting the same drawable to "thumb" and "track", is your intention?

See my codes:

**style.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <item name="android:fastScrollTrackDrawable">@drawable/fast_scrollbar_track</item>
        <item name="android:fastScrollThumbDrawable">@drawable/fast_scrollbar</item>

        <item name="android:scrollbarTrackVertical">@drawable/scrollbar_track</item>
        <item name="android:scrollbarThumbVertical">@drawable/scrollbar</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**fast_scrollbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <gradient
        android:angle="45"
        android:endColor="#ff00ff00"
        android:centerColor="#ff00ff00"
        android:startColor="#ff00ff00" />

    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
    <size android:width="4dp" android:height="50dp"/>
    <padding
        android:left="0.5dp"
        android:right="0.5dp" />
</shape>
```

**fast_scrollbar_track.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <gradient
        android:angle="45"
        android:endColor="#ffff0000"
        android:centerColor="#ffff0000"
        android:startColor="#ffff0000" />

    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
    <size android:width="4dp" android:height="50dp"/>
    <padding
        android:left="0.5dp"
        android:right="0.5dp" />
</shape>
```

**scrollbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <gradient
        android:angle="45"
        android:endColor="#ff00ff00"
        android:centerColor="#ff00ff00"
        android:startColor="#ff00ff00" />

    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
    <size android:width="4dp"/>
    <padding
        android:left="0.5dp"
        android:right="0.5dp" />
</shape>
```

**scrollbar_track.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <gradient
        android:angle="45"
        android:endColor="#ffff0000"
        android:centerColor="#ffff0000"
        android:startColor="#ffff0000" />

    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
    <size android:width="4dp"/>
    <padding
        android:left="0.5dp"
        android:right="0.5dp" />
</shape>
```

Prints of my device:

[image: fastScrollEnabled=true]

[image: fastScrollEnabled=false]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is like in your screenshots. But I can´t do fastscroll. Only scroll normal. I´ve added android:fastScrollEnabled="true" to my ListView (see Listview code in my question). But it doesn´t work. Is something still missing here?

Comment: Do a little test. Change the width of "track" to "50dp" (for example) and try pull the bar. On my project this works. If you want see the fastScrollText ([example](http://androidopentutorials.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/android-listview-fastscroll-style-attributes.jpg?b21cd7)), you need implement this on adapter. [This](http://androidopentutorials.com/android-listview-fastscroll/) tutorial can help.

Answer (score 1):

Now, I know why I couldn´t do fastscroll. I use a Viewpager as parent of my Listview and the scrollbar position was at the very right on the screen. I needed to set the scrollbar position a little bit more to the left side to touch the scrollbar correctly for fast scrolling:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:right="20dp"> <!-- Margin -->
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <gradient
                android:angle="45"
                android:centerColor="#CC6000"
                android:endColor="#CC5000"
                android:startColor="#CC5000"/>

            <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
            <size
                android:width="6dp"
                android:height="30dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Thanks again for your help, Luis!